# getElementsByTagName not working javascript, XML, google maps

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps

I cant get the data from the xml file using getElementsByTagName. What should I be using?

here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<markers>
    <marker>
        <lat>37.427770</lat> 
        <lng>-122.144841</lng>
        <name>Jackie</name>
    </marker>
    <marker>
        <lat>37.413320</lat> 
        <lng>-122.125604</lng>
        <name>Peter</name>
    </marker>
</markers>
```

Whole HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Common Loader</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="util.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var infowindow;
var map;

function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 13,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
downloadUrl("moredata.xml", function(data) {
  var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var latlng = new 
google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("lat")),
                                parseFloat(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("lng")));
    var marker = createMarker(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("name"), latlng);
   }
 });
}

 function createMarker(name, latlng) {
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map});
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
  if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: name});
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
return marker;
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:400px; height:300px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The file is an edited version of http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/xmlparsing/downloadurl_info.html

Im trying to get the data without using attributes

Comment: "title" tag is a reserved tag in case html. Can you change it to different tag and try? Also, "getElementsByTagName" returns array. So, the way you parse "lat"/"lng" may not work here. Share your html file so that we can have a test run here.

Comment: I've changed it and it still doesn't work

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please provide a better explanation of your problem. What happens and what do you expect to happen? Do you get any errors?

Comment: No markers are displayed

Comment: Ive tried to edit the demo so that the data in the xml file does not taken from attributes but within the elements

Comment: @devsathish: It's an XML document, so whether the tag name is `title` or not will not matter here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");` will result in an empty node list as you have absolutely no `<marker>` elements in your XML.

Next, `parseFloat(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("lat")` won't work as well. Assuming `markers[i]` would be the `<title>` element, the [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) would return a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList) of `<lat>` elements - which is something you probably cannot `parseFloat`!

Instead, you would need to get the first of the elements from the list, access its first [TextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Text) and get the [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeValue) from it - or at least somehow get the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent) from your `<lat>`.

Then, the callback function would look like

```
function(data) {
    var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("title"); // or "marker", after you've changed it
    console.log(markers);
    for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
        var lats = markers[i].getElementsByTagName("lat"),
            lngs = markers[i].getElementsByTagName("lng"),
            names = markers[i].getElementsByTagName("name");
        if (lats.length && lngs.length) {
            console.log("contents:", lats[0].textContent, lats[0].textContent);
            var lat = parseFloat(lats[0].textContent),
                lng = parseFloat(lats[0].textContent);
        } else console.log("didn't found <lat>/<lng>");
        if (!isNaN(lat) && !isNaN(lng) && names.length) {
            var name = names[0].textContent,
                latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                marker = createMarker(name, latlng);
                console.log("created marker", name, marker);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Did you use the `"title"` selector with the `<marker>` elements?

Comment: I've added some debug statements. What do you see in your console?

Comment: Is at least the XML downloaded correctly? Does that `downloadUrl` function provide an error callback?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is at,

```
var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
```

Try changing it to,

```
var markers = data.getElementsByTagName("marker");
```